# jquery p:last-child not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some data to my paragraphs, how ever it is only working for my first `p`.

I can make it put the data into my last `p` by using `p:gt(0)` but seems like I should be able to use `p:last-child`.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="quizEnd" style="display:none;text-align:center;">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <h2></h2>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#quizEnd p:first-child").text("Navn : " + quizName);
$("#quizEnd p:last-child").text("Email : " + quizMail);
```

Comment: `h2` is the last child, not the `p` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because that `p` element *isn't* the last child. The `h2` elements is.

You could use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) instead:

```
$("#quizEnd p:last-of-type").text("Email : " + quizMail);
```

You could also use the [`.last()` method](http://api.jquery.com/last/) or the jQuery [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector:

```
$("#quizEnd p:last").text("Email : " + quizMail);
```

```
$("#quizEnd p").last().text("Email : " + quizMail);
```